# Positive definiteness of solution to Sylvester / Lyapunov equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Given square matrices $A,Q$ with $Q>0$ the matrix equation known as the Lyapunov equation is given by

$$A^TX+XA+Q=0.$$

Lyapunov's theorem state that the solution $X$ is symmetric and satisfies $X>0$  if $A$ is hurwitz. Let us now consider the generalized "Sylvesters equation" for square matrices A,B,C

$$AX+XB+C=0.$$
Let us assume that $A,-B$ does not have common eigenvalues. Then there is a solution to the sylvester equation (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation))

**question:**

Is there an analogous criteria that can be put upon $A,B,C$ so that if $C$ is symmetric and $C>0$ then there exist a solution $X$ which is symmetric and $X>0$?

Comment: What do you mean by $C>0$, $x^\top C\,x>0\,\forall\,x\neq0$? I assume that $C$ doesn't have to be symmetric?

Comment: well we can assume that $C$ is also symmetric for simplicity. I added it

Comment: If $C$ is symmetric then it can be shown that $X$ would only be symmetric if $A=B^\top$. A non-symmetric $C$ would make it more difficult (and interesting).